# Minifig keychain value

Tags: value, collectable-minifigures

I'm new to collecting minifigs and have a pretty basic question about the value of keychains.

I found a seller offering rarer minifigs at 1/3 of there price on bricklink, they are genuine lego but they useto be keychains and have had the chain and screw removed to make them into "normal minifigs".

I know keychains have the legs fused to the body and will have small hole in the head after removal of the keychain but how does this affect the value of the minifig ?

What should be the correct price for a keychain minifig compared to its normal minifig version ?

Comment: The value of something to you is whatever you're willing to spend for it. It's very subjective. If you're interested in what value others have assigned to a certain part, you can look at the recent sales on bricklink by checking the [price guide](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3001#T=P&C=11) tab for the part.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker except you cant, bricklink does not list keychain versions, that's the exact reason for the question.

Comment: it does - under [Gear > Key Chains](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=G&catString=334). Granted, there might not be many recent sales, or items for sale, under that category. But that's because they're not as popular as actual minifigs.